# How to set the activity content based on the current screen orientation?

Tags: android

I simply want to do:

```
if(getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    setContentView(R.layout.search_portrait);
else
    setContentView(R.layout.search_landscape);
```

The problem is - getRequestedOrientation always returns -1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just changing the layout, you should really think about putting your portrait layouts in `/res/layout` and your landscape layouts in `/res/layout-land` (with the same names) and Android will select the correct layout automatically.

Comment: Tell me, will this also work for some strange situations like: landscape with QWERTY keyboard, landscape large... all relevant mentioned on this link: http://books.google.com/books?id=QdcYzuQx0DYC&pg=PA212&lpg=PA212&dq=/res/layout-land&source=bl&ots=xKaskx_2JU&sig=NjWDE3msogiveEHG4L5HdNWO2yc&hl=en&ei=HUIuTPuFFMH_nQeI6LneAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%2Fres%2Flayout-land&f=false

Comment: I've not tried such exotic screen configs myself, but yes, I believe it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` or `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`  to your manifest for this activity. It will be the default orientation... that's because [`getRequestedOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getRequestedOrientation%28%29) "*Return the current requested orientation of the activity. This will either be **the orientation requested in its component's manifest**, or the last requested orientation given to setRequestedOrientation(int).*".

Answer (score 0):

It must works properly, use this

```
 if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    else
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

And also place landscape xml file in

> /res/layout-land

Note: Layout file name must be same in all layout directories

i.e

- res/layout/activity_main
- res/layout-land/activity_main